# DateTime.TryParse implementation issue

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code where I need to determine if the received value is DateTime, if so, return 0 otherwise return the value in order to calculate sum:

```
row["Total"] = months.Sum(kv =>
                            {
                                DateTime dateValue;
                                if (!DateTime.TryParse(kv.Value, out dateValue))
                                {
                                    return double.Parse(kv.Value);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    return 0;
                                }
                            });
```

but these values are being treated as DateTime as well?

```
1726.07

4756.06

1.08

1.27

1.11
```

will every double value be treated as DateTime then?

Comment: what is `months`? how does it get these values set in the first place? that seems like the real problem..

Comment: try specify a format that is needed to match

Comment: Why not try the `double.TryParse` first? :D In any case, guessing at types of data is always tricky. You want to avoid that in the first place.

Comment: If you know the format you could use `DateTime.TryParseExact`.

Comment: @Sayse months is a dictionary with this structure <int, string> where string can either be a date or a double/int value.

Comment: @Ali - My point is that `months` doesn't appear to have consistency with the data that it holds. If at all possible, I would fix that problem before it escalates further

Comment: Use proper `CultureInfo` or datetime format.

Comment: @Ali  Sayse, is right, I think you are trying to fix the wrong problem and want to fix 'damaged' data. Fix the data in the first place, it has to be consistent, otherwise you will face a myriad of other problems later on.

Comment: @MichalFranc Actually this dictionary is being used to store data for various data points where any data point can have a date time type of data in it and this is a property contained within a type i.e. data point name, now each data point can have dynamic months selection for example 12 months, 13 months or 24 months period, so we dynamically populate this dictionary object. Please suggest any improvements It'll be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What if you do it 'all the way around' :

```
row["Total"] = months.Sum(kv =>
                            {
                                double toReturn = 0;
                                if (!Double.TryParse(kv.Value, out toReturn )) return 0;

                                return toReturn;            
                            });
```

Sometimes double values can be parsed using DateTime.Parse but i don't believe you can parse date like "22/06/2015" to double. And you don't really need this 'else' statement.

Other option would be to use DateTime.TryParseExact and specify format for your date...

Answer (score -1):

You can try this..

```
DateTime dateValue;
months.Where(kv=>(!DateTime.TryParse(kv.Value, out dateValue))).Sum(kv =>double.Parse(kv.Value));//Sum of values where values are not datetime
```

Comment: Please don't just make random guesses. Your code will have the same effect as the OP's.

Comment: Now as per @ali comment <int, string> ...he can try this